# Hoppers not working Spigot 1.7.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

My hoppers are connected to the chest (I shift-right-clicked to connect), however, the hoppers just store items in them rather then the chest. What could be causing this?

Plugins: 45
TimTheEnchanter, MOTDColor, WorldEdit, mcore, Vault, PEX, HealthBar, iControlU,  CombatTag, LWC, WorldGuard, TreeAssist, RTKP, Commandspy, MineResetLite, DamageIndicatorHolograms, ChestCommands, KBPL, Blood, ColoredTags, vampire, BukkitWebby, ClearLagg, ProtocolLib, Votifier, HolographicDisplays, mcMMO, GAListener, PluginTools, CCTV Camera, Essentials, QuickShop, LibsDisguises, VirtualPack, MoreSounds, TouchscreenHolograms, PhatLoots, CraftBook, Factions

Comment: Is there a worldguard or faction region on the area you are in? Has the chest or hopper got LWC protection? A picture of how you have set it up could also help.

Answer (score 1):

LWC also has a command to allow hoppers. Simply type:

`/lwc flag hopper on` and left click the chest.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. My problem was that the chest had LWC protection on it. Just /cremove on the chest and hoppers will work :D